# Hadoop 2.6 start-dfs.sh errors on Centos 6.7

Tags: centos6, hadoop2

I use this [tutorial](http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/#) to install Hadoop 2.6 on Centos 6.7 with Java 1.8.0_72 and everything goes well before execution of start-dfs.sh from Hadoop-home/sbin/srart-dfs.sh. Below is the output:

```
[hadoop@10 sbin]$  start-dfs.sh
16/02/26 21:47:40 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
localhost: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
localhost: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
localhost: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
localhost: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
localhost: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
0.0.0.0: /etc/bashrc: line 65: id: command not found
0.0.0.0: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
16/02/26 21:47:46 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

It seems there is something wrong with /etv/bashrc @ line 65. But, I checked and there is nothing I modified.

I run CentOS 6.7 final releas using Parallel VM manager of my Mac which is a 64-bit machine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Edit your core-site.xml and add this part:

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
```

Then create the folder accordingly, example command:

```
mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp

chown yourHadoopUsername:yourHadoopGroupName /app/hadoop/tmp

chmod 777 /app/hadoop/tmp
```

Format your datanode:

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

Start your hadoop:

```
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```